# What can I compare an object with using instanceof operator?

Tags: java, instanceof

```
class A{}
A a = new A();
Class a1 = A.class;

System.out.println(a instanceof A);   //true
System.out.println(a1.isInstance(a)); //true
System.out.println(a instanceof a1);  //compile error
```

the`Class.isInstance`is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator. So I think "A" is "Class" object,but why compile error? And  the object of "instanceof" right is what type?

Comment: Maybe something about "reliable types"? [JLS 15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Because using `instanceof` you should provide class name, not an object representing info about this class (i.e. not object of class `Class`). `isInstance` uses `Class`-**object**, `instanceof` - **name** of the calsss.

### Examples

```
System.out.println(a instanceof A);   //<object> instanceof <class name>
System.out.println(a1.isInstance(a)); //<Class object>.isInstance(<object>)
System.out.println(a instanceof a1);  //error: <object> instanceof <Class object>
System.out.println(A.isInstance(a));  //error: <class name>.isInstance(<object>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Class its type, not instance.

```
System.out.println(a instanceOf a1);  //compile error
```

this line like "this object TYPE is type of OBJECT"
this no make sense.
a is object of TYPE "CLASS"
a1 is object of TYPE "A"

Answer (score 0):

See [`instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) in the specification.

> ```
> System.out.println(a instanceOf A);   //true
> ```

No, that's a syntax error. `instanceof` doesn't have a capital `O`. But `a instanceof A` is `true`, yes.

> ```
> System.out.println(a instanceOf a1);  //compile error
> ```

Again, `instanceof` has a lower case `o`. But yes, it would be a compilation error, because you're checking `a` against `A.class`, not `A`.

The operand on the right-hand side of `instanceof` must be the name of a refererence type, not an instance of the `Class` class. `A` is the name of a reference type. `A.class` is an instance of the `Class` class.